# Is there a font that can't be recognised by an OCR?

Tags: ocr

I am trying to write a document that can only be read by humans. The document content can't be copied. For that purpose, I am converting its pages to pictures and adding them back to a PDF file. The main issue is that any OCR program can get back the whole written text, especially that the page is going to be clear (as opposed to a scanned book) which will increase the OCR accuracy.

So, is there a font that can't be recognized by an OCR. Otherwise, is there a technique that will make my document only readable by humans, yet unrecognised by an OCR? (for instance, adding a specific background, etc...)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think the answer depends on what computer you are trying to prevent from reading your document. For example, if you just want to prevent web search engines from indexing the content, you probably don't need to do a lot more than convert the pages to images. On the other hand, if you are concerned about a more active or malicious attempt to read the contents with a computer, there's not a huge amount you can do since you encounter the [analog loophole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole) - if a human can read it, it can be copied.

Comment: The leg hair font is probably not recognizable by any off-the-shelf OCR solutions: http://www.bitrebels.com/design/the-fascinating-font-created-from-leg-hair/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general OCR does not recognizes text by identifying their ‘fonts’, instead they do it  by analyzing the features and shapes of characters, means it looks for similarities in the figure open areas, shapes of the different texts, and letters in the file being scanned for conversion. *(That’s why it can also recognizes handwritten documents which are not using any fonts for that matter)*.

This process of identifying text through their feature is knows as `Intelligent Character Recognition`

I don’t think there can be a certain answer to your question that which font to use to make it unreadable by OCR but just to make it a more harder for a general OCR try using some [calligraphic fonts like this one](http://www.dafont.com/before-the-rain.font) which doesn’t follow general character features, hence hard for computers software to read (this is also the main idea behind CAPTCHA).

But again this may give a general OCR a hard time but still it’s not 100% successful solution, plus it will also make it really hard for any human to read.

Comment: What about a font that changes constantly. I mean that every single character of this font is written in a different font. Does this kind of fonts exist?

Comment: There exists many [`weird` fonts](http://www.fontspace.com/category/weird) having different shapes etc. for every character
But again you emphasized that your document will be for public reading and I don’t think anyone would like to read a document written with such fonts.

Comment: This is meant to be as an anti-plagiarism technique. You can read the text but you can never copy and paste from it. And even if you are willing to copy what you are reading, you'll find yourself forced to make some changes, so writing your very own material in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) technology, it shares your aims so should have already found solutions/pitfalls to your difficulties.

Comment: You want to embed a CAPTCHA into a PDF to prevent making a screenshot of that? Well...

Comment: No, not all. I said take a look at the technology - for examples of character obfuscation and how advanced it now needs to be in order to fool OCR systems. Plenty of image samples of distorted-but-readable words and the work's been done to demonstrate the effectiveness.

Comment: The main issue with CAPTCHA is that it will give you terrible headache after reading two lines of the document, no more. In addition, one single character will take a huge space compared to any other character written in a standard font. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: I second that, this is not a solution for a text meant to offer information to a human reader.

Comment: Then maybe the question isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real solution to what you want. It is a typical example of trying to hold back whilst trying to publish at the same time. This makes little sense.

There are some special fonts not recognized by out-of-the-shelf OCR solutions. The user would require an additional license to get a plugin recognizing those fonts. An example is the old german "Fraktur" fonts. But it is pretty hard to read for humans too :-)

Comment: In this case, I think I have to change the background of my document in order to make it harder on OCR to analyse it. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: That won't help. Every OCR system brings options to handle bad light, missing contrast and things like that. That is part of the standard toolbox of any usable OCR system, sometimes even applied (semi-) automatically. _And_ it also makes your text hard to read for humans.

Comment: I can understand that: if you can read it with your eyes, then an OCR can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Using graphic watermark in your document can confuse OCR.

Comment: Do you know any good software that can do this work? I don't seem to find the appropriate one to use with my document. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I don't really know, but please Google it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that some OCR engine, such as [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract2), has trouble handling connected or [cursive scripts](http://www.fontspace.com/category/cursive,script) (joining glyphs). You may want to try them and find out.